# spacy is creating two separate tokens for a unique word present in two different positions

Tags: spacy, tokenize

I am unclear on how spacy tokenizes words that appear again in a doc. In the example below, there are two sentences, and start with the word "He". Should this word result in one token? Does spacy tokenize every word (and more) in the document even if the words are repeated?  If tokens are used to create embeddings, will this result in 2 vectors for the word "he"??? Appreciate any help.

code:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Doc
import json
s = "He didn't want to pay $20 for this book. He didn't want to eat pizza also!"
doc = nlp(s)
doc_json = doc.to_json()
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(doc_json, indent=2)


mytokens = json.loads(json_formatted_str)['tokens']
for token in mytokens:
  if(token['lemma']=='he'):
    print(token)
```

```
Output:
{'id': 0, 'start': 0, 'end': 2, 'tag': 'PRP', 'pos': 'PRON', 'morph': 'Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Person=3|PronType=Prs', 'lemma': 'he', 'dep': 'nsubj', 'head': 3}
{'id': 12, 'start': 41, 'end': 43, 'tag': 'PRP', 'pos': 'PRON', 'morph': 'Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Person=3|PronType=Prs', 'lemma': 'he', 'dep': 'nsubj', 'head': 15}
```

Q: Will these two tokens result in two embeddings/vectors for the word "he"? That doesn't seem right- so some gap in my understanding here.

Thanks!

I looked up spacy documentation, looked at several questions here and on google, but could not find any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#tokenization), "spaCy’s tokenization is non-destructive, which means that you’ll always be able to reconstruct the original input from the tokenized output". Put differently, each word will result in a separate token, regardless of whether that word has occurred before. If this wasn't the case you would not be able to reconstruct the original input since you would be missing words.

Tokens and embeddings are not the same thing:

- A **token** is a part of a text, in this case a word or a punctuation mark. "Tokenization" is the process of splitting a text into segments. Technically such a segment (=token) could be a single character or a phrase consisting of multiple words. However, creating one token per word is the most common approach.
- An **embedding** is the representation of a token in vector space. This means an embedding is the numerical representation of a token. The idea is that similar words will have similar embeddings.

Imagine a language consisting of only four words:  "cat", "dog", "run", "walk".  If you wanted to create embeddings for these words it could look something like this:

```
"cat" --> [9, 0]
"dog" --> [8, 0]
"run" --> [0, 4]
"walk" --> [0, 5]
```

If you were to map this as coordinates on a graph you would see that "cat" and "dog" are near to each other and "run" and "walk" are close together, but "cat" and "dog" are far away from "run" and "walk".

Looking at your example, the embeddings for both tokens of "He" will be exactly the same, since it's the same word:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "He bought a book. He eats pizza. She is there."
doc = nlp(text)

he1 = doc[0]
he2 = doc[5]
she = doc[9]
pizza = doc[7]


print(he1.similarity(he2)) # Prints 1.0
print(he1.similarity(she)) # Prints 0.805
print(he1.similarity(pizza)) # Prints -0.101
```

"He" and "She" also have pretty similar embeddings, but "He" is very different from "pizza".

In summary you get a token for each word, but only one embedding for tokens that are the same (i.e. one embedding per distinct token).

**EDIT:**
The line `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` loads a language model that contains pre-trained word embeddings. This means the word embeddings are created during the creation (=training) of the language model and already exist when you load the language model. When you use the language model to tokenize your text, it associates the tokens with their matching embeddings.

The larger the language model you load, the more likely it is to contain an embedding for all words in your text. It is still possible that your text might contain words that did not exist in the training corpus (=text collection) of the language model, especially if your text contains lots of technical terms, names, or abbreviations. These are called **out-of-vocabulary (OOV)** words.

There are different ways to handle OOV words: The simplest way is to just assign a zero vector representation to unknown words (i.e. an embedding containing only zeroes). This is not super useful since it doesn't capture any information about the word. I think by default SpaCy uses the context of the word in the text and its linguistic features to create an embedding for OOV words. This is done for you automatically, so you generally don't need to worry about it if you are just getting started. This is a [nice description of how SpaCy deals with OOV words](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10591) and how you can change that behavior to work best for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about tokenization. Yes, now I understand what they meant by saying spacy is non-destructive- every word would need a token for this. Understand this now. However, in your code, you are comparing "token similarity". Are you taking token for 'he1', finding a "vector" for this token in some embedding (database? dictionary?), and then comparing it with the "vector" for the token for "he2"? How are these embeddings created? How do we know our 'token for he1' will have a corresponding token/word/vector in this embedding database? Thanks again!

Comment: @SatyaR I edited my answer to add more information.

Comment: Really appreciate all your explanations! How does spacy map a token for the word in the input with its corresponding embedding? What is the common entity that associates the two- how are they "joined"? I have read that tokenization and embeddings can be done separately, by different algorithms. This makes it even more difficult to understand how spacy's tokens can be associated with non-spacy created embeddings! I wonder if spacy extracts the lemma (word) from its token, and then checks if that word/lemma is in the vector space. (Is token a number internally???)

Comment: @SatyaR Maybe open a new question for that? That way other people with the same question will have an easier time finding the information than if it is in the answer to this question.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thank you for all your help in educating us new to this field. Much appreciated.